# Form submit show div and post data

Tags: php, html, post

So I've got a form which need to `post` data to a hidden div which I want to show when the form is `submitted` so when the user clicks `submit` it needs to `show` the div and the `posted results`

```
<div id="lootnumbers">


<form method="post" name="lootNumber" onsubmit="show(); return false;">
    Choose your 2 lucky numbers!
    <input type="number" name="quantity1" min="1" max="5" /><br>
    <input type="number" name="quantity2" min="1" max="5" /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
</div>
<div id="loot_dice" style="display:none;">
    <?php $first = $_POST['quantity1'];
          $second= $_POST['quantity2'];

          echo $first;
          echo $second;
    ?>
    <div id="die2" class="dice">0</div>
        <button id="roll" onclick="rollLoot();">Roll Dice</button>
    </div>
```

and the js file

```
function show() {
    var div = document.getElementById("loot_dice");
    if (div.style.display == 'none') {
        div.style.display = '';
    } else {                       
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Problem is that it does show the div when submitted but it wont post / show the results (I tried using `form action 'index.php` in which the hidden / shown div is located (the form is also located in index.php)

Comment: Google ajax in php

Comment: name of both the input are same ??

Comment: Sorry mistake @AditShah edited. but it still shows ` Undefined index: quantity in ... `

Comment: Also NEVER call anything in a form you need to script `name="submit"` since it kills the submit event handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div id="lootnumbers">
    <form method="post" name="lootNumber" action="">
        Choose your 2 lucky numbers!
        <input type="number" name="quantity1" min="1" max="5" /><br>
        <input type="number" name="quantity2" min="1" max="5" /><br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
<?php $style=""; if(empty($_POST)) { $style = 'display:none;'; } ?>
<div id="loot_dice" style="<?php echo $style; ?>">
    <?php 
        if(!empty($_POST)) {
            $first = $_POST['quantity1'];
            $second= $_POST['quantity2'];
            echo $first;
            echo $second;
        }
    ?>
    <div id="die2" class="dice">0</div>
    <button id="roll" onclick="rollLoot();">Roll Dice</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have inline style for your document. Maybe your function is showing it, but when form is submited and page is reloaded, it becomes invisible again.

You can try something like:

```
<div id="loot_dice" style="display:<?= if(isset($_POST['quantity1'])) ? 'block' : 'none' ?>;">
```

Or, like @Bikash says to you, try something like ajax or jQuery to achieve it.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: quantity1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\gamePHP\index.php on line 47
since I haven't posted anything it can't get the post

Comment: Sorry, It was an example, not a complete solution. I've updated my example, now it should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant this

```
<form method="post" name="lootNumber">
    Choose your 2 lucky numbers!
    <input type="number" name="quantity1" min="1" max="5" /><br>
    <input type="number" name="quantity2" min="1" max="5" /><br>
    <input type="button" value="show" id="but"/>
</form>
</div>
<div id="loot_dice" style="<?PHP if (!isset($_POST["quantity1"]) || empty($_POST["quantity1"])) echo "display:none" ?>">
    <?php $first = $_POST['quantity1'];
          $second= $_POST['quantity2'];

          echo $first;
          echo $second;
    ?>
    <div id="die2" class="dice">0</div>
        <button id="roll" onclick="rollLoot();">Roll Dice</button>
    </div>


window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("but").onclick=function() {
    var form = document.forms[this.form.name];
    var div = document.getElementById("loot_dice");
    div.style.display = div.style.display == 'none'?'':'none';
    setTimout(function() { form.submit(); }, 3000);
  }
}
```